# understanding `nodejs` async file read

Tags: node.js

I am trying to understand `nodejs` async behavior. Consider

```
### text file: a.txt ###
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
{{b.txt}}
3. Donec et mollis dolor.
{{c.txt}}
########################

### text file: b.txt ###
2. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris.
########################


### text file: c.txt ###
4. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. 
########################

var readFile = function(file) {
    fs.readFile(file, "utf8", function (err, file_content) {
        if (err) console.log("error: " + err);

        file_content.split(/\n/)
            .forEach(function(line) {
                var found = line.match(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/);
                found ? readFile(found[1]) : console.log(line);
            });
    });
};
```

The output I want is

```
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
2. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris.
3. Donec et mollis dolor.
4. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit.
```

The output I get is

```
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
3. Donec et mollis dolor.
2. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris.
4. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit.
```

How do I fix this? What is the most idiomatic way to accomplish such a task?

**UPDATE:** I want to note here that I *do not* want to use `readFileSync` or `async` (for now, at least). For now, I want to understand the right way to do this with plain JS and, in the process, get better understanding of async programming.

Comment: you can make use of readFileSync or you make use async library for achieving this.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but I *do not* want to use `readFileSync` or `async` (for now, at least). For now, I want to understand the right way to do this with plain JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're essentially asking to do is to make the line-by-line iteration wait for an async operation `readFile(found[1])` to finish before proceeding to the next line.  Since it's an async operation, it won't pause your Javascript execution.  Because it doens't pause the execution, the rest of the `.forEach()` continues to run and the results of the `readFile(found[1])` get interwoven with everything else that is going on.

The only solution to a problem like this is to take more control over the iteration so that the next iteration of the lines does not continue until your are done processing the current one.  You will have to stop using `.forEach()` and do a manual iteration.

Here's a general idea on how to make your function work with manual iteration:

```
var readFile = function(file, done) {
    fs.readFile(file, "utf8", function (err, file_content) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error: ", err);
            done(err);
            return;
        }

        var lines = file_content.split(/\n/);
        var cntr = 0;

        function nextLine() {
            var found, line, more = false;
            while (cntr < lines.length) {
                line = lines[cntr++];
                found = line.match(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/);
                if (found) {
                    readFile(found[1], function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            return done(err);
                        }
                        nextLine();
                    });
                    more = true;
                    // break out of the while loop and let this function finish
                    // it will get called again when the async operation completes
                    break;
                } else {
                    console.log(line);
                }
            }
            // if we're all done, then call the callback to 
            // to tell the caller we're done with all async stuff
            if (!more) {
                done(null);
            }
        }
        // start the first iteration
        nextLine();
    });
};

// call it initially like this
readFile("somefile.text", function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: your comment makes sense. Could you please give me an example of how exactly do I *do a manual iteration* ?

Comment: thanks @jfriend00 for the code. This helps a lot. The only edit I would make is to add `'var done = function(err) {if (err) console.log(err); return; };` to the code.

Comment: @punkish - The variable `done` is something you pass to `readFile()`.  That is up to the original caller to pass a function to it so it can know when it is all done.  I've added an example of that at the end.